# Syncfusion does auto conversion of 1,4 to 1.4 reading values and taking to datatable

Tags: excel, syncfusion

Why syncfusion is reading 1,4 as 1.4 I checked Excel column it was text now in same column we have 1,2,3 it's reading as is how to fix I tried with display text but it's null for 1,4 I am stuck I am using worksheet.exportdadatatable version 18 of syncfusion.
I tried with explicitly looping and reading but no luck

Need help on resolving this issue during reading data from xlsio to datatable in c# for column as is not convert 1,4 to 1.4. I am in 4.7.2 framework

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this link](https://support.syncfusion.com/agent/tickets/545502) for the reported issue.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to reproduce the issue at our end. However, we suspect that the 1,4 is stored as a number and the 1,2,3 value is stored as text. The system culture that is used for viewing the Excel document uses the decimal separator as a Comma(,). So, the valid number 1.4 is viewed as 1,4 in Excel and the "1,2,3" value is viewed as text which is not a valid number. But, while exporting the data to the data table, the number 1.4 only exported.

If it does not fit your case, please share us issue reproducing sample for us to proceed further.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.